# Passing value in the @Ajax.ActionLink Function

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how to pass value in the function

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Back to list", "list", "Security", 
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "show" })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470623%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Back to list", "list", "Security", new { YourValue = "Value" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "show" })
```